# Adding data to column to activate a trigger then removing it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table that has a trigger that will activate when an update is performed. I would like to force this trigger to run by adding a value to the last name but only for specific users.

What I'm thinking is to make this work, I would need to take the value of the `lname` and add something to it like '$'. This would make the trigger run and then rerun some SQL to remove the '$' from the `lname`.

I think it would look something like this:

```
Update table set lname = (current_value_OF_LNAME & "$")
where active = 1
```

Then

```
Update table set lname = (Remove($ from current_value_OF_LNAME)
```

Sorry for the pseudo code but I wanted to put this out there to see if this is the best way to do this or if there is a better way. Or if there is a way to just force this to run that would be acceptable too.

Thanks and sorry for the questions being muddy.

Comment: This seems like it would work, but one thing to note is that the trigger will be run twice (once for the addition of the `'$'` and once for the removal of the `'$'`).

Comment: This is true, I don't mind that it will get fired twice I just want it to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
Update table set lname = concat(lname,'$') 
 where active = 1
```

then

```
Update table set lname = substr(lname,1,length(lname)-1)
 where active = 1
```

Are you alone on the DB or could more rows be added or updated. I hope not. If yes you may query like this (still not perfect but helps)

```
Update table set lname = substr(lname,1,length(lname)-1)
 where substr(test,-1) = '$'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and see what I get.